# Uploading html into Rails app via CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a marketplace app that allows users to upload a csv file with product listings. One of the fields is a description field. I'd like to allow users to upload html tags in the csv description field and want rails to process the html when loading it. How do wrap the description field below to do that?

And is there a way I can limit which tags can be used? I only want to allow basic formatting tags.

My import method is below:

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

def self.import(file, userid)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|

      listing_hash = {:name => row['Product title'], :description => row['Description'], :sku => row['Product_id'],
                      :price => row['Price'], :category => row['Category'], :inventory => row['Quantity in stock'],
                      :userid => userid}.tap do |list_hash|
                        list_hash[:image] = URI.parse(row['Image']) if row['Image']
                        list_hash[:image2] = URI.parse(row['Image2']) if row['Image2'] 
                        list_hash[:image3] = URI.parse(row['Image3']) if row['Image3'] 
                        list_hash[:image4] = URI.parse(row['Image4']) if row['Image4'] 
                            end

      listing = Listing.where(sku: listing_hash[:sku], userid: listing_hash[:userid]) 

      if listing.count == 1 
        listing.first.update_attributes(listing_hash)
      else
        Listing.create!(listing_hash)
      end


    end # end CSV.foreach
end # end self.import(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to sanitize the description to make sure only safe tags and attributes are accepted.

```
sanitize(row['Description'])
```

And if you want to specify the tags yourself you can do it as well.

```
sanitize(row['Description'], tags: %w(p h1), attributes: %w(id class))
```

Check out [the rails sanitize helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) documentation for more options.

Or if you're outside a rails app or don't have access to the view helpers, you can use the [rails-html-sanitizer](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer) gem. The documentation is quite straightforward.